# Implementing 'const' interface method in C++ managed

Tags: c#, managed-c++

I need to implement C++ interface in C++ managed:

```
class MyInterface
{
    virtual int Get() const = 0;
};
```

How can i implement this interface with 'const' method in C++ managed with ability to import implementation from C# class library (to unit test it?

At this point i have PIMPL implementation for managed, which implements raw methods (not interface) with the same signature, but without 'const'. and in my high-level implementation i'm using 'const_cast'. I don't like this way, and it even doesn't work as well:

```
class MyImplementation: public MyInterface
{
    public:
        /*virtual*/ int Get() const
        {
            return const_cast<??>(??_impl).call();
        }
    private:
        msclr::gcroot<MyImplementationImpl> _impl;
};
```

Comment: You've stated a requirement. What is your question?

Comment: Make sure your question contains a `?` symbol somewhere...

Comment: It is not a managed interface.  You cannot implement it with a managed class.

Comment: Are you consuming that interface from C# or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I stopped on a such solution:

```
class IInterface
{
public:
    virtual int Get() const = 0;
};

class Implementation : IInterface
{
public:
    virtual int Get() const
    {
        return const_cast<ManagedImplementation^>(_impl.get())->Get();
    }

private:
    mutable msclr::auto_gcroot<ManagedImplementation^> _impl;
};

public ref class ManagedImplementation
{
public:
    int Get()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```